# Difference between high memory and high memory area

Tags: memory, memory-management, ram, cpu-architecture

Can somebody please explain me the difference between the terms high memory and high memory area. I have always came across these terms. I searched a lot about these terms but still i didn't got exactly how they are different.As far as I know both are the parts of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High memory is used in contrast to low memory, which is a block of memory at the beginning of memory which is typically reserved for kernel use. High memory area as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory_area), refers to a specific small (65,520 byte) block at the beginning of extended memory on Intel processors. You can read more [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20010502091809/http://www.pcguide.com/ref/ram/logicHMA-c.html).